# How to better this regex?

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I have a list of strings like this:

```
/soccer/poland/ekstraklasa-2008-2009/results/
/soccer/poland/orange-ekstraklasa-2007-2008/results/
/soccer/poland/orange-ekstraklasa-youth-2010-2011/results/
```

From each string I want to take a middle part resulting in respectively:

```
ekstraklasa
orange ekstraklasa
orange ekstraklasa youth
```

My code here does the job but it feels like it can be done in fewer steps and probably with regex alone.

```
name = re.search('/([-a-z\d]+)/results/', string).group(1) # take the middle part
name = re.search('[-a-z]+', name).group()                  # trim numbers
if name.endswith('-'):
    name = name[:-1]                                       # trim tailing `-` if needed
name = name.replace('-', ' ')
```

Can anyone see how make it better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex should do the work:

```
/(?:\/\w+){2}\/([\w\-]+)(?:-\d+){2}/
```

Explanation:

- `(?:\/\w+){2}` - eat the first two words delimited by `/`
- `\/` - eat the next `/`
- `([\w\-]+)`- match the word characters of hyphens (this is what we're looking for)
- `(?:-\d+){2}` - eat the hyphens and the numbers after the part we're looking for

The result is in the first match group

Comment: Thanks for a try. However I've tested it at regex101.com and found no matches at all.

Answer (score 1):

I cant test it because i am not using python, but i would use an Expression like

```
^(/soccer/poland/)([a-z\-]*)(.*)$
```

or

```
^(/[a-z]*/[a-z]*/)([a-z\-]*)(.*)$
```

This Expressen works like "/soccer/poland/" at the beginning, than "everything with a to z (small) or -" and the rest of the string.

And than taking 2nd Group!

The Groups should hold this Strings:

- 1. **/soccer/poland/**
- 2. **orange-ekstraklasa-youth-**
- 3. **2010-2011/results/**

And then simply replacing "-" with " " and after that TRIM Spaces.

PS: If ur Using regex101.com e.g., u need to escape / AND just use one Row of String!
Expression

```
^(\/soccer\/poland\/)([a-z\-]*)(.*)$
```

And one Row of ur String.

**/soccer/poland/orange-ekstraklasa-youth-2010-2011/results/**

If u prefere to use the Expression not just for soccer and poland, use

```
^(\/[a-z]*\/[a-z]*\/)([a-z\-]*)(.*)$
```

Comment: Have you tested it? I've run a test at regex101.com and unfertunately it found no matches. Also the first regex is too strict, there will be other names other than `soccer/poland`.